# Bundle Structure For Sidebar In Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony and I'd like to know what the recommended way to add a sidebar to my site is. The sidebar will primarily consist of 4-5 different elements/widgets all using database data.

Should I use a service container within my main bundle to render the different aspects of my sidebar and pass MySQL data to it, or should I create a sidebar/block bundle to take care of all this?

As a bonus, most of the sidebar data will only change on a weekly basis, so if I could find a way to cache this to avoid making the same database calls, that would be great. This might be beyond the scope of this question though, but is worth mentioning just in case it makes a difference to the answers given.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this totally depends on what you want. If you consider the sidebar as an isolated feature, it is wise to put into an own bundle. If it is interconnected with your main bundle, put it into the main bundle.

As for the caching:
Symfony caches views. But on top of that you can cache data. Doctrine provides such a cache layer. Search for that in the documentation of Doctrine or elsewhere in the Internet.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now thinking of putting it in it's own block bundle and using that for displaying any blocks of frequently used content across the site. If I'm doing this, will I just use a service container within an otherwise empty bundle, or use a controller but without any routes to make it visible? If I use a service container then wont accessing doctrine be a problem? Really appreciate your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "If I use a service container then wont accessing doctrine be a problem"?